# Mysql Inner Join with OR condition - Query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

Here's my query

```
SELECT tum.user_id, tum.first_name, tum.last_name 
FROM di_webinar t
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_registrants ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
LEFT JOIN tbl_event_attendees tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
INNER JOIN tbl_user_master tum ON tum.user_id = ter.user_ref_id OR tum.user_id = tea.user_ref_id
WHERE t.di_ref_id ='93'  
GROUP BY tum.user_id
```

This query works fine gets me the expected results but its very slow due to the OR condition on inner join. Here's what i tried to make it better.

```
SELECT tum.user_id, tum.first_name, tum.last_name 
FROM di_webinar t

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT event_ref_id, user_ref_id 
FROM tbl_event_registrants GROUP BY user_ref_id 
) ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT event_ref_id, user_ref_id 
FROM tbl_event_attendees GROUP BY user_ref_id 
) tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id

-- LEFT JOIN tbl_event_registrants ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
-- LEFT JOIN tbl_event_attendees tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
INNER JOIN tbl_user_master tum ON tum.user_id = ter.user_ref_id OR tum.user_id = tea.user_ref_id
WHERE t.di_ref_id ='93' 
GROUP BY tum.user_id
```

But i'm not sure thats the best way to go.

Here's the explain plan

```
    id  select_type  table                  type    possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             key                                 key_len  ref                                 rows  Extra                                               
------  -----------  ---------------------  ------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ----------------------------------  -------  --------------------------------  ------  ----------------------------------------------------
     1  PRIMARY      t                      ref     FK_di_webinar_direfid                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     FK_di_webinar_direfid               2        const                                  1  Using temporary; Using filesort                     
     1  PRIMARY      <derived2>             ref     <auto_key0>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <auto_key0>                         4        univarie_uni_db.t.webinar_ref_id      36  Using index                                         
     1  PRIMARY      <derived3>             ref     <auto_key0>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               <auto_key0>                         4        univarie_uni_db.t.webinar_ref_id      11  Using index                                         
     1  PRIMARY      tum                    ALL     PRIMARY,UNQ_tbl_user_master_LoginRefId,idx_user_master_membership_ref_id,FK_user_master_board_ref_id,FK_tbl_user_master_school_id,FK_tbl_user_master_profile_statusID,FK_tbl_user_master_payment_statusID,FK_tbl_user_master_url_ref_id,idx_tbl_user_master_FirstName,idx_tbl_user_master_LastName,fk_tbl_user_master_CityRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_StateRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_CountryRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_EthnicityRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_FamilyIncomeRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_ScholarshipImportanceRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_ReasonStudyAbroadRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_PrimaryFinancingRefId,fk_tbl_user_master_CitizenRefId,Idx_tbl_user_master_CriticalPercent,Idx_tbl_user_master_PresentClass,Idx_tbl_user_master_ClassStatus,srinivas_test  (NULL)                              (NULL)   (NULL)                             35641  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)  
     3  DERIVED      tbl_event_attendees    index   fk_tbl_event_attendees_UserRefId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          fk_tbl_event_attendees_UserRefId    5        (NULL)                               845  (NULL)                                              
     2  DERIVED      tbl_event_registrants  index   fk_tbl_event_registrants_UserRefId                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        fk_tbl_event_registrants_UserRefId  5        (NULL)                              3568  (NULL)
```

Comment: Please submit your explain plan here

Comment: You select all Webinars with all their registrants and attendees, but once you are there, you simply list all users, each with one sample Webinar? So in case a user took part in three Webinars, you Show the user with a random one of the three? Why?

Comment: Correct, all i need is distinct users who attended/registered for all the webinars that are there.

Comment: Is there any way that i write the above query with out the OR condition?

Comment: You are showing all distinct users that had a part in at least one Webinar. Per user you show a random one of their Webinars. What is it good for to show a sample Webinar per user?

Comment: we can skip the t.* values from the query, our concern is to list the users who are attended/registered for all the webinars

Comment: Okay, just one more question: You said twice you want the users  attended/registered for **all** the webinars. So far I thought you mean those who took part in at least one webinar. Do you mean to show only those users who took part in **all** webinars?

Comment: yeah, i update the queries above. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comments you said, you don't have to show a sample Webinar per user. Then you don't even have to select from the Webinar table. After all you simply want all users that had a part in a Webinar. So select from tbl_user_master and make sure the user id is mentioned in one of the two tables tbl_event_registrants and tbl_event_attendees.

```
select first_name, last_name
from tbl_user_master 
where user_id in
(
  select user_ref_id
  from tbl_event_registrants
  union all
  select user_ref_id
  from tbl_event_attendees
);
```

MySQL can be very slow on IN clauses and UNION queries however. So here is the same with two EXISTS clauses:

```
select first_name, last_name
from tbl_user_master tum 
where exists
(
  select *
  from tbl_event_registrants ter
  where ter.user_ref_id = tum.user_id
)
or exists
(
  select *
  from tbl_event_attendees tea
  where tea.user_ref_id = tum.user_id
);
```

If you only want to show users that took part in *all* Webinars, then you'd have to find the total number of webinars and compare with the number of Webinars associated with a user.

```
select first_name, last_name
from tbl_user_master tum
where 
(
  select count(distinct event_ref_id)
  from
  (
    select event_ref_id
    from tbl_event_registrants
    where user_ref_id = tum.user_id
    union all
    select event_ref_id
    from tbl_event_attendees
    where user_ref_id = tum.user_id
  )
) = (select count(*) from di_webinar);
```

EDIT: Here is the same with a join:

```
select tum.first_name, tum.last_name
from tbl_user_master tum
join
(
  select user_ref_id, event_ref_id
  from tbl_event_registrants
  union
  select user_ref_id, event_ref_id
  from tbl_event_attendees
) ref on ref.user_ref_id = tum.user_id
group by tum.user_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from di_webinar);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
 SELECT tum.user_id, tum.first_name, tum.last_name 
 FROM di_webinar t
 LEFT JOIN tbl_event_registrants ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
 LEFT JOIN tbl_event_attendees tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
 INNER JOIN tbl_user_master tum ON tum.user_id = tea.user_ref_id
 WHERE t.di_ref_id ='93'  
 GROUP BY tum.user_id

 union
 SELECT tum.user_id, tum.first_name, tum.last_name 
 FROM di_webinar t
 LEFT JOIN tbl_event_registrants ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
 LEFT JOIN tbl_event_attendees tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
 INNER JOIN tbl_user_master tum ON tum.user_id = ter.user_ref_id 
 WHERE t.di_ref_id ='93'  
 GROUP BY tum.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
SELECT tum.user_id, tum.first_name, tum.last_name
From tbl_user_master tum
Left Join (
    Select ter.user_ref_id as kTER, tea.user_ref_id as kTEA
    FROM di_webinar t
    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_registrants ter ON ter.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_attendees tea ON tea.event_ref_id = t.webinar_ref_id  
    WHERE t.di_ref_id ='93' 
    GROUP By ter.user_ref_id
    ) a On a.kTER = tum.user_id or a.kTEA = tum.user_id
GROUP BY tum.user_id
```

My recommendation, table in subquery, make as a table before